# How to change styles according to data type in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make ng-repeat propagate a list from an array containing trues and falses. How do I make it so that the falses are in red, and the trues are in green?

This is my code right now:

```js
$scope.profileCompare = {

        You: {
            name: "You",
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
            questionImportance: [false, true, false]
        },
        Pizza: {
            name: "Pizza",
            questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
            questionImportance: [false, false, true]
        },
        Greenie: {
            name: "Greenie",
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
            questionImportance: [true, false, false]
        }
    }
```

```html
  <h2 ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in profileCompare">{{key}}</h2>
  <ul class="comparison-list">
    <li ng-repeat="importance in value.questionImportance track by $index">
      {{importance}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-repeat-end class="comparison-list">
    <li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" ng-if="answer == true" style="color: green">
    {{answer}}
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" ng-if="answer == false" style="color: red">
    {{answer}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This isn't doing it, because it goes through the array once and puts all the trues in the front not showing any falses, then it goes through the array again and shows the falses and no trues.

How do I make it so it shows a green true and a red false at the proper positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  following way. ng-class takes object which has key as css class and value as expression which is evaluated by angular to retrieve the value. if its truthy, then it applies that class or removes that class (if already applied).

```
<style>
.red{
color:'red';
}
.green{
color:'green';
}
</style>

<li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" ng-class="{green:answer, red: !answer}">
```

Comment: sorry. I meant ng-class

Comment: how would I assign multiple classes to a condition?

Comment: {green:answer, red: !answer, newclass:newconditionExpreession} in this object you can add multiple classnames with their conditional expressions.
If you mean multiple classes with one expression, you can copy the same expression for multiple classes. {green1:answer, green2:answer}

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you can't use style property, you need to define css class styles, and then apply that class with angular

```
<style>
.clGreen { color: green; }
.clRed { color: red; }
</style>
```

then use `ng-class` like this

```
<li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" ng-class="{clGreen:answer, clRed:!answer}">
{{answer}}
</li>
```

Note: Ok, I lied, you can use angular in style attr, but only interpolating like this

```
<div style="color: {{color}}"></div>
```

and that does not help you in your current problem

Comment: how would I assign multiple classes to a condition?

Comment: `ng-class="{clGreen:answer, clOther:answer, clRed:!answer}"`